# Offset.value=Stringを行う際に、Stringの文字数が約8000文字を超えるとメモリー不足でVBAが停止します

Tags: vba

以下のようなVBAのコードで、ある文字列をString型のtestに入れて、あるRangeから特定位置ずらしたセルにその文字列を代入するさい、文字列Testが約8000文字(英数で約8000 characters) を超えると、添付のエラーが表示されてしまいます。
8000文字以下の場合は正常に動作します。

どなたか解決方法、または原因をご存じでしたら教えていただけると幸いです。

**該当コード**

```
Desc.Offset(i + 1, 0).Value = test
```

**エラー画面**

[image: エラー]

Comment: 詳しく見てみたところ、　1Lineに約8000文字を超える場合はOut of memoryになるようです。　改行コードがあり、1Lineが8000文字以下の場合は、セルの最大文字数約30000文字でも問題なく動作しました。　改行コードまでの文字数を数えて回避は可能ですが、文字代替案をご存じの方がいたら教えていただけると幸いです。

Comment: ちょっと再現できなかったので excel のバージョンと完全な再現コードを載せてもらえますか？

Comment: Nick さんへ。質問はいつでも [edit] することができるので、質問に直結するような内容はコメント欄ではなく質問本文に追記してみてください。